# Extend set of fixed values (enum, sealed interface, sealed class...) without repeating them

Tags: java, kotlin, architecture, sealed

I have a class that has a fixed set of filters  and is responsible for fetching data from an search API (lets say "PERSON;CAR;BUILDING").
Now I want to wrap this search class inside an "Extended" search (by using something like an adapter pattern), and add an additional endpoint which fetches also ANIMALS (another endpoint).
For the Extended class I have the Combined filter "PERSON;CAR;BUILDING;ANIMALS" where the first three still work for the one API and the last one (ANIMALS) works for the second API.

My question is, is there a nice approach to make these filters somehow compatible/dependant on each other. The best solution would be to extend the first filter with the items for "Combined" filter. I have been playing around with sealed interfaces/classes but so far I could not find a nice way to do that. My solution for now is to use enums (copy the values from all filters) and make a mapper from the combined filter to the real search filter. The issues with this approach are  that I am duplicating all filter values and in case the search filter gets extended it could easily be forgotten to also extend the combined filter.

Edit: added code

```
enum class SearchFilter { PERSON, CAR, BUILDING }

class GeneralSearch {
  fun search (filter: SearchFilter)
}

class AnimalSearch {
  fun search ()
}
```

Combine both api-s:

```
enum class CombinedSearchFilter { PERSON, CAR, BUILDING, ANIMALS }

class CombinedSearch (
      generalSearch: GeneralSearch, 
      animalSearch: AnimalSearch
) {
  fun search (filter: CombinedSearchFilter)
}
```

The issue is that the `CombinedSearchFilter` is duplicating the values from `SearchFilter` without any constraint.

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Edited the answer and added example code

Comment: How about making `SearchFilter`, `CombinedSearch` and `AnimalSearch` sealed interfaces? `Each filter could implement the interfaces that they "belong" to.

Comment: Maybe I don't get it, but what would I gain from it, I would still need to duplicate all values or?

Answer (score 1):

You can make `SearchFilter`, `CombinedSearch` and `AnimalSearch` sealed interfaces. Each filter (the enum values) would then implement one or more of those interfaces. You can make `SearchFilter` and `AnimalSearch` inherit from `CombinedSearch` as well.

```
sealed interface SearchFilter: CombinedFilter
sealed interface AnimalFilter: CombinedFilter
sealed interface CombinedFilter

object Person: SearchFilter
object Car: SearchFilter
object Building: SearchFilter
object Animal: AnimalFilter
```

or put the individual filters in other objects if you want code completion:

```
sealed interface CombinedFilter

sealed interface SearchFilter: CombinedFilter {
    object Person: SearchFilter
    object Car: SearchFilter
    object Building: SearchFilter
}
sealed interface AnimalFilter: CombinedFilter {
    object Animal: AnimalFilter
}
```

Because of this type hierarchy, `CombinedSearch.search` would be able to take all 4 of `Person`, `Car`, `Building` and `Animal`.

The downside of this is that if you happen to have another combination of APIs, you would need to modify the declarations of all the involved filter types. For example, if there were a third API with a `FooFilter` type:

```
sealed interface FooFilter
object Foo1: FooFilter
object Foo2: FooFilter
```

And you want a `CombinedFilter2` that combines `FooFilter`s and `SearchFilter`s, you'd need to add:

```
sealed CombinedFilter2

sealed interface SearchFilter: CombinedFilter, CombinedFilter2
                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
sealed interface FooFilter: CombinedFilter2
                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

---

If you want code-completion on `CombinedFilter`, then I can't think of any way unless you get rid of `sealed`.

Represent each filter as anonymous object properties, and wrap `object`s around them. The combined filters will have two properties, each initialised to the `object` containing the constituent filters.

```
// this can still be sealed
sealed interface CombinedFilter

interface SearchFilter: CombinedFilter
object SearchFilters {
    val person = object: SearchFilter {}
    val car = object: SearchFilter {}
    val building = object: SearchFilter {}
}

interface AnimalFilter: CombinedFilter

object AnimalFilters {
    val animal = object: AnimalFilter {}
}

object CombinedFilters {
    val search = SearchFilters
    val animal = AnimalFilters
}
```

---

Another option is to keep using enums, but `CombinedSearch` would take a `Either<AnimalFilter, SearchFilter>`.

```
enum AnimalFilter { ANIMAL }

sealed interface Either<out L, out R> {
    data class Left<L>(val value: L): Either<L, Nothing>
    data class Right<R>(val value: R): Either<Nothing, R>
}
```

Example usage:

```
combinedSearch.search(Either.Right(AnimalFilter.ANIMAL))
combinedSearch.search(Either.Left(SearchFilter.CAR))
```

The downside of this is that it's more inconvenient on users' side - there is whole lot more "ceremony".

Comment: About the first approach, I tried this also, but if done like this you lose all the code completion benefits. In order to know which filters exist, in worst case, you would need to jump between multiple files, and this was too big of a drawback so I dismissed it. About the second, as you said, it is not so nice on the caller side and I can't enforce that on a caller (I am building a library) just to make my code nicer

Comment: @rimes Code completion? That's a high bar. I can think of a more code-completion-friendly approach, but that would sacrifice the `sealed` nature of the interfaces. i.e. someone else can make a new `SearchFilter` or `AnimalFilter`.

Comment: Shoot, I am open to any new approach :)

Comment: @rimes (I edited the answer if you haven't noticed already)

Comment: Sorry I missed your update. Thank you for the effort, but I would still have to take a  compromises  for any solution so far. For example for the caller I would not like to split the filters into "animal" and "search" but to have a flat list of items (just like a posted with the flat enum). It seems that what I want is currently not really achievable (at least not with kotlin)